# Upload files to separate folder using media API in WordPress with rest-api plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, directory, wordpress-rest-api

**Description:** I have a requirement that upload files to WordPress. Now I'm using rest-api plugin and uploading files with /media endpoint. But I can only upload files to a fixed folder.

**Requirement:** I need upload files to different folder in WordPress.

**Question:** How can I upload files to different folders with some parameters passing from client side with the media API? Better to use some plugins and no code change is preferred.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @happymacarts Actually I don't try any code for now. In my mind, maybe I can intercept the uploading request and change its destination path, But it's not expected way.

Comment: well SO is a coding forum so when you are ready come back and post some.